# How can I install bashdb on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, bashdb

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and noted that my bash db installations removed.

I tried to reinstall it, but apt can not find it.

```
m@m-XPS-M1530:~$ sudo apt-get -y update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release 
Reading package lists... Done
m@m-XPS-M1530:~$ sudo apt-get -y upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
m@m-XPS-M1530:~$ sudo apt-get install bashdb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bashdb
```

How can I install it?

Comment: The last version providing `bashdb` is Ubuntu 17.10 : https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&keywords=bashdb&searchon=names.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks, is there any way that I install an old version?

Comment: `bashdb` has no special dependencies.  Download the 17.10 version :  http://mirror.pacific.net.au/linux/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/bashdb/bashdb_4.3.0.91+ds-4build1_amd64.deb ... Install : `sudo gdebi Downloads/bashdb_4.3.0.91+ds-4build1_amd64.deb`

Comment: @KnudLarsen alternative, http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/bashdb/bashdb_4.3.0.91+ds-4_amd64.deb

Answer (score 5):

One of the comments in the questions suggests downloading the bash 4.3.0.91 package. However there is a version based on bash 4.4 and updated more recently. Also, I think 18.04 ships with bash 4.4.

Go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashdb/files/bashdb/4.4-1.0.1/ and look at the changes. since 4.3.0-91 and if this are of interest then download the tarball. From there it is the usual GNU-style build

```
$ tar xpf bashdb-4.4-1.0.1.tar* 
$ cd bashdb-4.4-1.0.1
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr  # I think /usr/local is the default
$ make 
# make check # optional
$ sudo make install
```

https://wiki.debian.org/RFP gives the process for asking for a adding a Debian package. It looks like https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bashdb is where you can get the address of past Ubuntu maintainers.